# Python 3: Parsing a date from a container string

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, python-3.x

I have a webpage from which I'm trying to get a date. I know what the format is, so the solution should be as easy as [`time.strptime(format)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/time.html#time.strptime), but the problem is this:
`If string cannot be parsed according to format, or if it has excess data after parsing, ValueError is raised.`
I'm trying to parse something that looks like:

```
<tr><td align="center"><b>Create time</b></td>
</tr><tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">Between August 1, 2012, 8:05 pm and August 1, 2012, 8:06 pm</td>
```

The corresponding format would be `%B %d, %Y` (it doesn't really matter which date, I just need a date).
I could use a regular expression (e.g. `([JFMASOND][a-z]{2,8}) ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})` ) to get the relevant part of the string out, but then I may as well just get the values themselves from the regex and do the necessary conversions myself. Is there any way to use strptime on the container string, so to speak? It shouldn't be too hard for strptime to just keep crunching on the string until it gets a format match...
(If I do have to do it myself, is there a better way than a regex?)

Comment: First of all, you are using an XML parser to parse the HTML, right?

Comment: @lkjoel: I wouldn't use an XML parser to parse HTML. Use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: What parsing? All I need is the date in the page.

Comment: @Dubslow: To make date parsing easier, you need to extract the text out of the the HTML, which is what a HTML parser does.

Comment: Yes, but the parser can't go further than tell me what's inside the <td>, and I need to clear out most of what's left anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used the [`parsedatetime`](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) module to extract dates from text. It works pretty well:

```
>>> import parsedatetime as pdt
>>> parser = pdt.Calendar(pdt.Constants())
>>> parser.parseDateText('Between August 1, 2012, 8:05 pm and August 1, 2012, 8:06 pm')
daysInMonth(8, 2012)
(2012, 8, 1, 17, 53, 18, 6, 218, 1)
>>>
```

It accepts almost all date formats with abbreviations except for `Sept.`, which I've posted to the bug tracker but they refuse to fix it, so I just replace `Sept` with `Sep` and it works fine.

Comment: Hmmm... I presume it could handle all the other HTML crap in the string as well? And I'm a little hesitant to use non-standard-library stuff, especially since it's no shorter than just a few lines of regex...

Comment: The HTML stuff shouldn't be there in the first place, so you need to clean it out somehow. As for the parser, what's wrong with using non-standard-library modules? It will work better than any home-made regex solution and will parse the dates for you, regardless of the format.

Comment: The whole page is 11 lines of tables; going through the bother of configuring an HTMLParser would be much more fuss than just passing the 11 lines of HTML into the pdt parser...

Comment: If you know the exact input, that's fine. If not, with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), you can parse the HTML in one line: `cleaned = BeautifulSoup(html).find('td', {'bgcolor', '#DDDDDD'}).text`.

Comment: http://factordb.com/frame_moreinfo.php?id=1100000000525873586 (view source) It wouldn't work. Any HTML parser would need to look at the string anyways, which is what the whole question was about. I do know that parsers are out there, and I decided that they would not be of use.

Comment: `soup.findAll('td', {'bgcolor': '#DDDDDD'})[-1].text` grabs the text inside of the last dark table row.